# Trojans detected - formatting required?

Tags: windows-7, trojan

Microsoft Live Essentials detected the following items today:

> Exploit: Java/CVE-2010-0840.HH VirTool:
>
> Win32/VBInject.gen!HO
>
> TrojanDownloader: Java/OpenConnection.OU

It's since cleaned these items and I've now downloaded the latest definitions and have also initiated a full scan (using MS Live Essentials). I'm also running a full scan using Webroot's Spy Sweeper.

I'm quite paranoid about the effects of these detections and I'm wonder if I should simply reformat my machine?

Comment: Are you a sysadmin? Why not just re-image this machine and move on?

Comment: No. But I'll have to talk to my sysadmin. I just a ton of data on this machine that will take a significant chunk of time to back up. The question basically is to find out which option is better:
Option 1 - Faster, but let the AV/Spyware programs do their thing.
Option 2 - Slower, back up, migrate the data, clean up and re-image the machine.

Time is important here, so I'd like to know your thoughts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Comment: @techie007, they are not asking how to disinfect, but if it is a trusted PC after disinfection and should they clean install the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the compromise was on the administrator level, then you can't assume the system is trusted anymore (any files could have been modified to put a back door, change behavior, etc.)  So to be thorough you would have to re-install.

If the compromise was on the user level, then you can just delete/re-add the user.